# How do I get the guests emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I'm trying to get the event guests email addresses into my a google sheets I have

I'm trying to use the function 
events[i].getGuestByEmail(email)
But I don't know how to pull in the string (it says that email is not defined.

```
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event 
Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", 
"Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", 
"MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event", 
"Guests"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,15);
range.setValues(header);


// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out 
 starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
  var row=i+2;
  var myformula_placeholder = '';
  // NOTE: I've had problems with the getVisibility for some older     events not having a value, so I've had do add in some NULL text to make     sure it does not error
  var details=[[mycal,events[i].getTitle(), even    ts[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(), events[i].getGuestByEmail(email))]];
```

I need it to populate the spreadsheet with guests email addresses

Comment: Can you show the code where you set `events`?

Comment: For `events[i].getGuestByEmail(email)`, I do not see `email` defined anywhere. If you're trying to get all the guests you would call `events[i].getGuestList()` (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getGuestList()).

Comment: Hi
I didnt define email
im trying to figure out how to define it.
Basically all i need is to be able to get the email address of the guests on the calendar events to a spreadsheet, Ill be happy if can just help me out and type the function I need to put in the code in order to do that.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Then I think you want to use `getGuestList()` instead. Hard to say without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: I tried using that. but it outputs "event guest" instead of their names or email addresses into the cells in the spreadsheet... how do i fix that?
I can post the whole code if that would help you

Comment: `getGuestList()` returns an array. You'll have to iterate through the array and pull out each guest's e-mail.

Comment: Ok got it.
I know its a little weird but I really dont know much coding or scripting and its something I want to do for work.. could you explain how do I do that?

Comment: How about `Logger.log(getGuestList().join(','));` ?

Comment: how can I implement that? @cooper

Comment: [Logger Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the guests’ emails, you would need to use `events[i].getGuestList()` as suggested by @IMTheNachoMan however, to use it in your code the way you want it will be a bit different. `getGuestList()` will get you an array of guests to that event, you can wire the following code to keep track of their emails:

```
var guests = events[i].getGuestList();
var guestEmails;

for (var j = 0; j < guests.length; j++){
    guestEmails.push(guests[j].getEmail();
    Logger.log(guestEmails[j]);
}
```

This will give you an array of the emails and you can access it later and add it to your spreadsheet. Documentation for the `getGuestList()` method [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getEmail()).

Comment: Thank you so much!
I am getting this error for some reason ..typeError: Cannot call method "getGuestList" of undefined. 
can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you update your code to show where `events` comes from?

Comment: Sure! this is the code i used.. it pulls up the events from a shared calendar 
https://docs.google.com/a/usfca.edu/spreadsheets/d/1reNHZwbt4YXu-LdUcoLpv6QR4jnw9TqDH_Evmdn1D1c/copy

Comment: Are you running the code I posted inside a loop? otherwise the i will no the declared and `event[i]` will indeed be undefined, try running it with `event[0]`

Comment: Omitted parenthesis, must be guestEmails.push(guests[j].getEmail());